# Using external list of PCs for clustering

Tags: seurat, clustering, pca

I am going to use principal components (PCs) comes from calcPCA function in URD program for clustering my cells in Seurat; So

```
seurat@dr$pca=URD_object@pca.load

> seurat <- FindClusters(
+     object = seurat, 
+     reduction.type = "pca", 
+     dims.use = 1:8, 
+     resolution = 1.0, 
+     print.output = 0, 
+     save.SNN = TRUE
+ )
Error in GetDimReduction(object = object, reduction.type = reduction.type,  : 
  cell.embeddings slot doesn't exist
```

There is `seuratToURD` function but there is not URD to seurat function I guess so I could use URD object for clustering in seurat
How I can overcome this error please? I want to see when I am using PCA from URD what would be my clustering by SNN algorithm in seurat

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do this, and even better--there is documentation for how to do it! No surprise coming from the Satija Lab. In the vignette they perform multidimensional scaling, but the idea is the same. `cmdscale()` returns the cell embeddings. `SetDimReduction()` is the Seurat function you are looking for. No manual editing using `@` required.

The authors use add mds embeddings, but if you want to add your own pca embeddings swap out `"mds"` for `"pca"` and `mds` for `URD_object@pca.load`.

```
# Before running MDS, we first calculate a distance matrix between all pairs
# of cells.  Here we use a simple euclidean distance metric on all genes,
# using object@scale.data as input
d <- dist(x = t(x = pbmc@scale.data))
# Run the MDS procedure, k determines the number of dimensions
mds <- cmdscale(d = d, k = 2)
# cmdscale returns the cell embeddings, we first label the columns to ensure
# downstream consistency
colnames(x = mds) <- paste0("MDS", 1:2)
# We will now store this as a new dimensional reduction called 'mds'
pbmc <- SetDimReduction(object = pbmc, reduction.type = "mds", slot = "cell.embeddings", 
    new.data = mds)
pbmc <- SetDimReduction(object = pbmc, reduction.type = "mds", slot = "key", 
    new.data = "MDS")
```

See [the dimensional reduction vignette](https://satijalab.org/seurat/dim_reduction_vignette.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already demential reduction matrix (PCs) by another program (URD) and I want to store that in Seurat object for clustering

Comment: In `SetDimReduction()` replace `"mds"` with `"pca"` and `mds` with `URD_object@pca.load`.

Comment: Thank you                                                                                                              > pbmc <- SetDimReduction(object = seuset, reduction.type = "pca", slot = "cell.embeddings", 
+                         new.data = URD@pca.scores)
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  ‘cell.embeddings’ is not a slot in class “data.frame” 
>

Comment: Try `str(seuset)` to ensure your Seurat object is whole. You might also `RunPCA()` within Seurat and return to cell.embeddings to ensure the format of your external embeddings is identical. I'd also recommend changing `reduction.type="pca"` to something like `reduction.type="pca.external"` just to ensure you aren't dealing with some protected fields in the S4 object.